# Are there any reasons not to mix Multiprocessing and Threading module in Python

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, python-3.x

I am considering using Python to implement a program, which requires extensive multi-threading. Another requirement is that it will run on desktops, so having many processes, will make the application appear to be messy and harder to kill (in Task Manager). Therefore, I am considering using both the Threading and the Multiprocessing modules to reduce the number of processes. As far as I understand the GIL will apply only to a single process. My question is: Is there any reasons not to mix using the two modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note:  This warning does not apply to windows.

Be careful!  There is a nasty bug lurking with locks when combining threading and multiprocessing which is exposed when using the logging module as well.  I've been bitten for the last week with child processes occasionally hanging.  Now that I've disabled logging, so far so good (though not the best solution!).:

https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/Main/PythonLoggingThreadingMultiprocessingIntermixedStudy

http://bugs.python.org/issue6721

Comment: 6721 bug has nothing to do with threading/multiprocessing on Windows

Comment: Right, missed the windows tag.

Answer (score 1):

Other than basic principle of [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).... go for it, there shouldn't be any issues.