# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable in python's multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing for doing some works. But, I got that error. Why did that happen? Below is my sample code

```
def work(x, y):
    #doing something

def work_process(x, y):
    p = []

    for i in x:
        p.append(Process(target=work, args=(x, y)))
        p[i].start()

    for t in p:
        t.join()

    return result
```

Comment: This looks fine. You are probably going to have to show some more code.

Comment: IF you copy and paste the *entire* error message, it will be more helpful.  This is because the error usually shows the offending line of code in the message.  It also includes the line number on which the error occurs, which will help you know what extra code you should show us when you edit your post.

Comment: Two other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728236/exception-thrown-in-multiprocessing-pool-not-detected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535680/python-debug-tools-for-multiprocessing

Answer (score 0):

I have written something helpful for debugging multiprocessing errors. It can show you the full traceback of an exception/error in the other process.

Download [RemoteException.py](https://gist.github.com/niccokunzmann/5763860)

```
import RemoteException

@RemoteException.showError
def work(x, y):
    #doing something
```