# How to capture stderr from Python mulitprocessing process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

How do you capture the stdout/stderr of a specific target of a process launched from Python's `mulitprocessing.Process` library, ideally without requiring special modifications to the target function?

e.g.

```
p = Process(target=myfunc)
p.daemon=True
p.start()
p.join()
print p.exitcode, p.stderr.getvalue()
```

I know how to override sys.stdout/sys.stderr with a custom file object and use multiprocessing.Queue to redirect IO between processes, but this requires modifying the target function to write its output to the Queue.

Is something like this available with `Process`? I'm assuming it is on some level, since I'm able to see the process's output in the terminal when running, even if I can't record it from the parent process.

Comment: If you want an error message have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535680/python-debug-tools-for-multiprocessing/14327070#14327070 although that may not fit your use case.

Answer (score 1):

This is no answer but a long comment.

I would create a wrapper function that replaces sys.stderr and writes it to a file/pipe and then after/while the process ran the stderr is read into the parent. Reason:

**This seams difficult if you do not alter the function**

Multiprocessing does not use subprocess.
You subclass Process and set `Process.Popen` to replace `multiprocessing.forking.Popen`.
Replacing `multiprocessing.forking.Popen` must implement different code for the platforms 'win32' and 'not win32' leading to two different subclasses OR use subprocess.

Modifying `multiprocessing.forking.Popen` to use `subprocess` should be your best try from my point of view.

In `Process.start()`

```
from .forking import Popen
self._popen = Popen(self) # also self.Popen
```

In `multiprocessing.forking`

```
class Popen(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        # ...
        # for windows
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _subprocess.CreateProcess(
            _python_exe, cmd, None, None, 1, 0, None, None, None
            )
```

Now having a look at subprocess:

```
(p2cread, p2cwrite,
     c2pread, c2pwrite,
     errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
                            cwd, env, universal_newlines,
                            startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
                            p2cread, p2cwrite,
                            c2pread, c2pwrite,
                            errread, errwrite)
self.stdout = os.fdopen(c2pread, 'rU', bufsize)
```