# multiprocessing in python jump over process with no error

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have the following code which acts pretty strange.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.process_list = []
        self.event_list = []


    def run(self):
        self.process_list = []
        counter = 0
        n = 0
        while (n<1000):
            n += 1
            print("in while again")
            self.lock.acquire()
            print('after acquired lock')
            self.lock.release()
            self.event_list.append(Event())
            print('add event')
            p = Process(target=workerEmulator().run,
                        args=(self.lock, self.event_list[counter]))
            print('create process')
            self.process_list.append(p)
            print('add process')
            self.event_list[counter].clear()
            counter += 1
            print("about to start process")
            print("n="+str(n))
            p.start()
            print("new process started")
            print(": main process, active_children: " + str(multiprocessing.active_children()))


            del_list = []     # the list for storing index of the process/event to delete
            for i in range(len(self.event_list)):
                if (self.event_list[i].is_set()):
                    self.process_list[i].join()
                    print("one process finished, its exit code: " + str(self.process_list[i].exitcode))
                    print("this process is alived or not? " + str(self.process_list[i].is_alive()))

                    del_list.append(i)

            del_list.sort(reverse=True)
            for i in del_list:
                del self.event_list[i]
                del self.process_list[i]
                counter -= 1

            time.sleep(0.1)

        for p in self.process_list:
            p.join()
            print("one process finished, its exit code: " + str(p.exitcode))
            print("this process is alived or not? " + str(p.is_alive()))



class workerEmulator:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self, lock, event):
        print("a new process")
        self.lock = lock
        self.event = event

        time.sleep(20)
        print("after sleep")
        self.lock.acquire()
        print("in lock")
        self.lock.release()
        self.event.set()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    a.run()
```

As I thought, every print statement should be executed 1000 times. However, it is never the case, there are always a few times missing, then if we look at n, I noticed that n will jump over some number, for example, ... n=798...n=799...n=801...n=802... (n=800 missing). I don't see why this happens, could someone help?

Comment: How many are missing out of the thousand (minimum and maximum you've counted), and how consistent is it?  Is it always the same numbers for every run, or random?  Since you aren't relying on any kind of locking to preserve print output, have you confirmed that the text isn't split across the output from another process, e.g. "a new8 pro0cess0"?

Comment: usually less than 10 times, from 2 to 8 as I am testing it, but it will definitely lose some. The lock in print is a good suggestion, let me try by disabling output from child process. @MattJordan

Comment: @MattJordan Yes, you are right, after disabling child output, the problem is solved! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See Matt's comment, the problem is caused by child output intermingles with parent output.