# Running asynchronous python code in a Django web application

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

Is it OK to run certain pieces of code asynchronously in a Django web app.  If so how?

For example:

I have a search algorithm that returns hundreds or thousands of results.  I want to enter into the database that these items were the result of the search, so I can see what users are searching most.  I don't want the client to have to wait an extra hundred or thousand more database inserts.  Is there a way I can do this asynchronously?  Is there any danger in doing so?  Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as Django is concerned yes.

The bigger concern is your web server and if it plays nice with threading.  For instance, the sync workers of gunicorn are single threads, but there are other engines, such as greenlet.  I'm not sure how well they play with threads.

Combining threading and multiprocessing can be an issue if you're forking from threads:

[Status of mixing multiprocessing and threading in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984003/status-of-mixing-multiprocessing-and-threading-in-python)

http://bugs.python.org/issue6721

That being said, I know of popular performance analytics utilities that have been using threads to report on metrics, so seems to be an accepted practice.

In sum, seems safest to use the threading.Thread object from the standard library, so long as whatever you do in it doesn't fork (python's multiprocessing  library)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Answer (score 3):

Offloading requests from the main thread is a common practice; as the end goal is to return a result to the client (browser) as quickly as possible.

As I am sure you are aware, HTTP is blocking - so until you return a response, the client cannot do anything (it is blocked, in a waiting state).

The de-facto way of offloading requests is through [celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which is a task queuing system.

I highly recommend you read the [introduction to celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html) topic, but in summary here is what happens:

1. You mark certain pieces of codes as "tasks". These are usually functions that you want to run asynchronously.
2. Celery manages workers - you can think of them as threads - that will run these tasks.
3. To communicate with the worker a *message queue* is required. [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) is the one often recommended.

Once you have all the components running (it takes but a few minutes); your workflow goes like this:

1. In your view, when you want to offload some work; you will call the function that does that work with the `.delay()` option. This will trigger the worker to start executing the method in the background.
2. Your view then returns a response immediately.
3. You can then check for the result of the task, and take appropriate actions based on what needs to be done. There are [ways to track progress](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results) as well.

It is also good practice to include caching - so that you are not executing expensive tasks unnecessarily.  For example, you might choose to offload a request to do some analytics on search keywords that will be placed in a report.

Once the report is generated, I would cache the results (if applicable) so that the same report can be displayed if requested later - rather than be generated again.

Comment: Celery is absolutely valid, but does require extra system architecture.  I would use it without question if a task was heavy enough to require a significant amount of RAM or CPU, to keep the web servers unburdened.  In my opinion, using Celery to forward web requests is only useful if the infrastructure already exists or if the requests are sufficiently slow, as posting a task to the AMQP server is a request in and of itself, making it a bit redundant.  The code for invoking Celery tasks is simpler than multithreading, but not at the cost of having more infrastructure to pay for/maintain.

Comment: You don't need "infrastructure"; you can run celery on the same machine as your existing app; without impacting your application performance (as webservers are not CPU bound).

Comment: I consider anything that needs to run in parallel with the main server as infrastructure. It is an external entity that needs to be maintained ( system upgrades, monitoring, appropriate firewall settings, etc.). Also, saying that web servers are not CPU bound is a bit of a generalization as it depends on how/ what the server is running.  Also, if the CPU is completely pegged by outside tasks, or the system runs out of memory the responsiveness of the server will fail or it can be killed outright (oomkiller).  Again, I think Celery is a valid approach (easier to invoke, allows for growth, etc.)

Comment: However, since Celery is the popular approach, I wanted to offer a counter point as to why a more lightweight solution can at times be more appropriate.  In the end it falls to project complexity, the amount of different tasks that will be run in parallel and how heavy those tasks are that tips the scales one way or another.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid how do you query these when once the task starts and the page is rendered